# mobile.back not working inside UIWebView

Tags: jquery-mobile, uiwebview

I have two pages - A and B. When a user clicks on a link in page A, I open page B using

```
$.mobile.changePage('pageBurl');
```

When the user clicks on a link in page B, to go back to page A, I have

```
$.mobile.back();
```

This works in iPad safari browser, but not inside an app's uiwebview.

How can I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to use the attribute `data-rel="back"` on your link ?
This attribute work for me. Try to test